# How do I send a transaction to HashPack for signing?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hedera-hashgraph, hashgraph, hashpack

I am trying to sign a transaction on the frontend and send the signed bytes to the backend to execute the transaction. However, I am having difficulty signing the transaction. I have a HashConnect pairing with my app, and I have my signer, but I am not having any luck signing. I've tried several different things, and I'm currently here:

```
const transactionId = new TransactionId(AccountId.fromString(accountId));
const transaction = new TopicMessageSubmitTransaction()
    .setTopicId(id)
    .setMessage(JSON.stringify(message))
    .setTransactionId(transactionId);

const signedTransaction = await transaction.signWithSigner(signer);
```

I am receiving the following error:

```
TopicMessageSubmitTransaction.js:293 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'seconds')
    at TopicMessageSubmitTransaction.freezeWith (TopicMessageSubmitTransaction.js:293:1)
    at HashConnectSigner.signTransaction (signer.ts:66:1)
    at TopicMessageSubmitTransaction.signWithSigner (Transaction.js:990:1)
    at postReply (Thread.js:133:1)
    at onSubmit (Thread.js:252:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the error because you did not freeze the transaction. To fix your problem you have to freeze your transaction by calling `freezeWithSigner(signer)` Here is the example code

```
const transactionId = new TransactionId(AccountId.fromString(accountId));
const transaction = new TopicMessageSubmitTransaction()
    .setTopicId(id)
    .setMessage(JSON.stringify(message))
    .setTransactionId(transactionId)
    .freezeWithSigner(signer);
            
const signedTransaction = await transaction.signWithSigner(signer);
```